# Help finding adventure novel from the 70s or 80s, Operation Tango/Tonga/Tongo?

Tags: identification-request

I'm in Canada, and when I was in elementary school in the early 80's at a french school our little library had a shelf of english books available.

One of these these books was an adventure book for kids (maybe even YA). I'm pretty sure the title was Operation Tongo, but it could've been Tango or Tonga too I guess. It was a paperback novel, probably about 200 pages long.

The cover was a jungle scene, there was maybe a helicopter or plane, an explosion, and maybe a jeep or truck, and some armed soldiers running around.

The story was a military "man-on-a-mission" type of story. A soldier (or small team of soldiers) are sent into this jungle to take out some enemy base or something like that. It had a very Vietnam era feel to it.

I think the book predated my elementary school days, so it was probably published in the 1970's, but maybe even earlier.

Any help finding this book and its author would be great, thanks!

Comment: Quite possibly not Operation Tonga since [that's a WW2 codename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Tonga#References).

Comment: I don't see why that would preclude someone writing a book with the same name decades later, but ok. :/

Comment: ^_^ True. Just mainly saying you may get more false positives trying to chase that down.